# How to load default values in skuid model?

Tags: custom-field, default-value, defaults, skuid

#### Question

When I'm creating a new object in the Skuid page is there anyway for the model to pull in the defaults values for the object? For example, if I've set the default value for the field, `Date__c` to be `TODAY()`, I'd like the skuid page to load new records with that value.

Is this possible with native skuid functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, Skuid uses a Field's default Value when setting values on fields in new records, but Skuid currently does NOT support default value ***formulas***, such as `TODAY()`.

When attempting to set a default for Fields in new records, Skuid looks for information from the following sources:

1. Default values, such as true/false, or a Default Picklist value, specified in the Field's Salesforce metadata.
2. Active Conditions on the Model whose Operators are "=" or "starts with"

So if you have a Skuid Page that is, say, used for creating a new Contact record, you can add a Condition on your New Contact Model that achieves something similar, e.g.

- Field: My_Date_Field__c
- Operator: =
- Value: Single specified value, Today

Skuid supports a number of Date / Datetime Literals, but only Today, Yesterday, and Tomorrow can currently be used for setting default field values on new records.

[image]

[image]